# What is the meaning of "Boxing" in C# (as opposed to Java)?

Tags: java, c#

I'm learning C# from a Java background and had some confusion about `ValueType`s.  My understanding from reading MSDN's [C# vs Java](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360(v=vs.90).aspx) overview was that primitives are objects instead of having wrappers.  If that's the case, why do they need to be [boxed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk(v=vs.90).aspx) to call methods?  It looks like they mean something different than Java's autoboxing, but I'm not sure what.  It looks more like casting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Boxing is very similar concept in Java and C#. The difference is when it happens:

```
Character ch = 'a';
```

this will cause boxing in Java because 'a' is primitive and Character is class (wrapper).
In C# this:

```
Char ch = 'a';
```

will not cause boxing because `Char` is not a primitive type but is value-type class. To cause boxing in C# you need to cast object of value type to `object` reference.

```
object o = 'a';
```

**Edit**: As mentioned by HighCore in comment, there is important implication of the boxing mechanism in C#. Putting stuff into `List<int>` doesn't cause boxing and taking stuff out doesn't cause unboxing because List of ints is real list of unboxed ints.

Comment: I think it's also important to mention to a newcomer from java, that C#'s generics are properly designed and there is no such thing as "type erasure" and other abominations he might be used to from java, and that creating a `List<int>` is totally valid in C#.